# We will join you in an hour.We will be joining you in an hour

Tags: expressions, word-usage, differences

We will join you in an hour. We will be joining you in an hour. 
What difference in the meanings do you see in these sentences. 
Is it correct? 
We will join you=we have just decided. 
We will be joining you=a previous arrangement. 
I shared my views. 
Let see.
What do you explain about them?

Comment: Yeah , I read it. In fact,  I am confused about the meanings of these sentences.

Comment: @Josh61 that doesn't seem to answer the question because in this case a time duration is also specified. This means that the next task in both cases is indeed going to be of joining their friends / colleagues etc

Comment: @Nitika - I think it does, anyway you can  provide your own answer.

Comment: I am waiting for the correct answer. Brothers

Answer (score 1):

Both the sentences are variations of future tense: simple future and future imperfect.To me, in both the sentences we will join you for certain but whether we will keep your company is certain in the latter ie.(the sentence using future continuous form¶¶ sub+will+be+verb-ing¶¶)